# Mutual authentication with python as a CGI web app?

Tags: python, apache, ssl, cgi, pki

I'd like to make a simple python CGI script (hosted by apache in my case) that reads the client certificate and logs who accesses the script. My question seems simple but I can't find any info on the WWW: with a python CGI script, how do you grab the client cert? I already have a working script and SSL so just trying to break the code on the client certificate piece. I'm open to trying another web server but I want to keep it as vanilla as possible, so no web frameworks (django, etc)

Comment: One other possibility is to just write the server in python like [this](https://www.piware.de/2011/01/creating-an-https-server-in-python/). But even with that I'd still like to get the client cert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Apache HTTPD with mod_ssl then this is actually quite easy. You can instruct mod_ssl to export [SSL related information into environment variables](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#envvars) with this configuration directive:

```
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
```

You can then read all required information from environment variables without any external dependencies - for example basic CGI script written in Perl displaying commonName from client's certificate would look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

print "Content-type: text/html\n";
print "\n";
print $ENV{"SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN"}
```

I've written full length article about [SSL authentication in Apache HTTPD](https://www.jimrich.sk/2009/05/25/ssl-autentizacia-s-webovym-serverom-apache/) few years ago but it is only available in Slovak language. However it can be [translated to English with Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=sk&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jimrich.sk%2F2009%2F05%2F25%2Fssl-autentizacia-s-webovym-serverom-apache%2F&edit-text=).

Comment: I discovered this exact solution as well while waiting for an answer. With python the environment variables are stored in os.environ.items(). Thanks for the quick response!